# How to filter list using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of objects initially on load no filter should be applicable 
then on user selection combination list should be displayed accordingly.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vzndtnkp/2/)

I am not able to get what wrong did i done over here whole list i not displaying and only single selection works at a time.
For single selection i used

```
 return $scope.filter[stat.userStatus] || noFilter($scope.filter);
```

I cannot make both selection work together.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vzndtnkp/2/

Comment: One thing for sure is that in your code you have    $scope.filterByCategory = function(stat) which takes stat named parameter. You call this function in your filter without giving any parameters. So this at least breaks your filter.

Comment: stat is object of list

Comment: both selection working toghether i guess on fiddle

Comment: DropDown One is not working

Comment: Kunal - Your question even though it includes a fiddle is not clear. We are trying to guess what you want. On page load, do you want all the 3 users to be displayed and then on each selection to filter the list? You have admin in title, userStatus and role which further adds to the confusion. Anyway my take on your issue and here is the fiddle if it helps http://jsfiddle.net/sheth/6cLeuxcn/

Comment: It would do no harm to use some interpunction, as the text you have produced is pretty incomprehensible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filters can be [chained together](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/filters/chaining-filters-together.html), like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in mylist | filter:filterByStatus | filter:filterByRole">
```

The filters run from left to right, with each filter passing the filtered array to the next filter.

Here is a fork of [Mark's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/841435/mark-ni) fiddle, demonstrating this technique:
http://jsfiddle.net/2671uggu/

Answer (score 0):

**Please use the SAME naming and case everywhere in your code**

- `admin` is not the same as `administrator`
- `admin` is not the same as `Admin`

If I understand correctly, The basic idea follows,

```
    $scope.filterByCategory = function (stat) {
        //check if user has a status matching checkbox select
        var by_status = $scope.filter[stat.userStatus];
        //check if user has a role that matching dropdown list select   
        var by_roles = stat.roles.indexOf($scope.filter.selectedSearch) !== -1;

        return by_status || by_roles; //statisfy either of two will return true;
    };
```

Full demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6rqL6zxh/

Comment: This would give me result not of combination of filter

Comment: @KunalVashist change the last line to && if you want to apply both conditions. Otherwise I have no idea what you want :)

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get your code working. This is kind of a fix and a better approach would be making a filter(working on that as well).
Assumptions that I made :-

> By Member Status filter means checking 'userStatus'
>
> By ADMIN Status filter means checking 'roles'

Check out this [Plnkr](http://jsfiddle.net/f81gw2a9/2/)

I am filtering on the basis of an object which updates based on $scope.filter.

Changes to HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="item in mylist | filter:filterModel">
```

Changes to JS

```
$scope.filterModel =
        {
           "userStatus":"",
            "roles" : ""
        }
    $scope.$watch('filter', function() {
        var myModel =
        {
           "userStatus":"",
            "roles" : ""
        }
        if($scope.filter.administrator && $scope.filter.lead)
        {    
            myModel.userStatus="";
        }
        else if($scope.filter.administrator)
        {
            myModel.userStatus="admin";                
        }
        else if($scope.filter.lead)
        {
            myModel.userStatus="lead";
        }
        else
        {
            myModel.userStatus="";
        }
        if(angular.equals($scope.filter.selectedSearch,'Default'))
        {
            myModel.roles="";
        }
        else
        {
            myModel.roles=$scope.filter.selectedSearch;
        }
        $scope.filterModel=myModel;
   },true);
```

**UPDATE** : Mark's filter seems to be working correctly